# Is it possible to create a vertical funnel?

Tags: delphi, charts, teechart

The default TeeChart funnel is horizontal.

Is is possible by any means to have a vertical funnel?

Answer (score 2):

You can invert a pyramid chart. Unfortunately there seems to be no way to rotate a funnel by 90°.
Play around with it in the TeeChartOffice demo that you can download here http://www.steema.com/getfile/dc85e455496644c00663f6b081ce85db